# Python function to fill a list based on index number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this function to fill a list with object based on the desired index they should have.

Here the func:

```
def fill(lst, index, add, fillvalue=None):                                        
    '''Fills a list with the add value based on desired index'''                       
    '''Let the value in place if present'''                                                            
    for n in range(index):                                                        
        try:                                                                      
            if lst[n]:                                                            
                pass                                                              
        except Exception:                                                         
            lst.append(fillvalue)                                                 
    try:                                                                          
        if lst[index]:                                                            
            pass                                                                  
        else:                                                                     
            lst[index]=add                                                        
    except Exception:                                                             
        if index==len(lst):                                                       
            #This if check probably not mandatory                                               
            lst.append(add)                                                       
    return lst
```

edit: here's an usage example that would for example happen in a for loop

```
>>> my_list = [1, 7, 14]
>>> fill(my_list, 5, 6)
[1, 7, 14, None, None, 6]
>>> fill(my_list, 6, 12)
[1, 7, 14, None, None, 6, 12]
>>> fill(my_list, 3, 25)
[1, 7, 14, 25, None, 6, 12]
>>> fill(my_list, 4, 18)
[1, 7, 14, 25, 18, 6, 12]
```

Note:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 7, 14]
>>> fill(my_list, 1, 6)
#returns the list not modified, my_list[1] is already taken
[1, 7, 14]
```

It works good for my purpose (matrix generating). My matrixes are generated with many "for loops" passes, because the data I convert to is unordered. This is why the "None" elements are important in order to fill them out on a subsequent loop pass.

My questions are:

- I'm wondering if I made everything as simple as possible? Or if there
  were a lib, that would do the same job?
- For now the matrixes aren't so long but I guess, if I go further
  in my development, they will become big (1000+ lines). Should
  I somehow better use itertools?
- I also somehow thought of first using a dict {index: value} and
  convert it to a list when filled up. Would it be better practice?

Edit: Now that I pasted the code in here I notice the arg name "add" is blued. My Vim-editor didn't told me that... Is it a name already taken by the python core?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Can you add a usage example? it is not quite clear to me how to use your function properly and what exactly it should do.

Comment: @Graipher Thank you ! I edited the question with an example.

Comment: Using `except Exception:` like that is a bad idea, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `if lst[n]` is not sufficient to determine if the value at index `n` is `None`, `0` will also not pass the test. Use `if lst[n] is not None` or `if lst[n] is None`, depending on which one you want.
- The whole first loop is just trying to determine if you need to extend the list, but you could just do that:

  ```
  lst.extend([fill_value] * (index - len(lst) + 1))
  ```

  If the list is already long enough this does nothing, as a list multiplied by an integer smaller than one is the empty list, and extending with an empty list does nothing. It even works when you use negative indices.
- This also guarantees that the index exists, so you don't need the `try..except` anymore. But if you use `try` and `except`, always try to catch the narrowest exception possible. This way you make sure you don't catch an unexpected exception. In this case it would be an `IndexError` instead of the more generic `Exception`.
- The convention in Python is for functions to only do one of two things: either do not mutate the inputs and return a new output or mutate (some of) the input and return `None` (potentially implicitly). Your function falls into the second category.

With these changes your function could be a lot shorter:

```
def fill(lst, index, value, fill_value=None):
    """Place the `value` at index `index`,
    but only if the value already there is `None`.
    Extends the list with `fill_value`, if necessary.
    """
    # No-op if list long enough or index negative
    lst.extend([fill_value] * (index - len(lst) + 1))
    if lst[index] is None:
        lst[index] = value

my_list = [1, 7, 14]
# my_list = [1, 7, 14]
fill(my_list, 5, 6)
# my_list = [1, 7, 14, None, None, 6]
fill(my_list, 6, 12)
# my_list = [1, 7, 14, None, None, 6, 12]
fill(my_list, 3, 25)
# my_list = [1, 7, 14, 25, None, 6, 12]
fill(my_list, 4, 18)
# my_list = [1, 7, 14, 25, 18, 6, 12]
```

Note that you will not directly see the result anymore in an interactive session, since the list is no longer returned. But that's a feature, not a bug, as mentioned above.

Of course, if you need to do this multiple times directly after each other, you might want to define a function that needs to extend only once:

```
def fill_multiple(lst, indices, values, fill_value=None):
    lst.extend([fill_value] * (max(indices) - len(lst) + 1))
    for index, value in zip(indices, values):
        if lst[index] is None:
            lst[index] = value
```

Then you can use e.g a dictionary:

```
my_list = [1, 7, 14]
updates = {5: 6, 6: 12, 3: 25, 4: 18}
fill_multiple(my_list, updates.keys(), updates.values())
# my_list = [1, 7, 14, 25, 18, 6, 12]
```

I kept the indices and values separate so you can also just pass lists or anything else, not just a mapping. Depending on your usecase you might want to pass the dictionary to the function instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer. I like the way advanced coders are able to divide by 4 the line amount of some amateur code. Side question: from where comes this convention on functions? Or where could I read more about those conventions?

Comment: @Halavus It's actually surprisingly hard to find an authorative source for this, it is just conventional wisdom that it should be this way :). Even the [canonical StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027694/correct-style-for-python-functions-that-mutate-the-argument) about this has no sources.

Comment: @Halavus "[You might have noticed that methods like `insert`, `remove` or `sort` that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default `None`. 1 This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)" - Python docs. It doesn't really explain why tho.